# Trace IBM WebSphere WLTC0032W: One or more local transaction resources were rolled back

Tags: java, datasource, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

I wanted to know how to trace what code exactly caused the following warning in WebSphere.

> **WLTC0032W: One or more local transaction resources were rolled back during the cleanup of a LocalTransactionContainment.**

In our application, we have a lot of classes from where we obtain a JNDI DataSource and execute SQL and I wanted to know is there a way by turning debug on in test environment to exactly pin-point the class that causes this warning. I am unable to find exception stack trace in SystemErr.log.

Comment: I am not sure if adding any WebSphere trace well help but not sure exactly what to configure for debug trace of WebSphere to identify class causing WLTC0032W warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message indicates that you performed some local transaction work as part of that containment scope but did not commit. I suggest two options:

1) Commit the local transaction

```
connection.commit();
```

2) Putdata source to auto-commit

```
connection.setAutoCommit(true);
```